# Django models.py Circular Foreign Key

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

I have a django app which basically is just a photo album. Right now I have two models: `Image` and `Album`. Among other things, each `Album` has a foreign key to an `Image` to be its thumbnail and each `Image` has a foreign key to the `Album` it belongs in. However, when I try to use `manage.py syncdb` or `manage.py sqlall` I get errors saying the class not defined first in models.py isn't defined when it is used in the first class defined.

models.py (abridged):

```
from django.db import models
import os

class Album(models.Model):
    thumb = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='t_pics/images')
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='t_pics/images/thumbs')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

Error I get when I do `manage.py sqlall appname`:

```
[...]
 File "/path/to/file/appname/models.py", line 4, in ?
    class Album(models.Model):
  File "/path/to/file/appname/models.py", line 5, in Album
    thumb = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, blank=True)
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

I get the same error when I switch the order of the classes in models.py except it says `'Album' undefined` instead of `'Image' undefined` I also tried commenting the dependancy in the first class then uncommenting after everything else was successfully imported but that didn't help. How should I go about making this work? I'm reluctant to make an entire third class `Thumb` because it will have a lot of the same code as `Image` I'm also pretty sure I could manually add the foreign key to the database but I want this to be clean and not hackish.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don't actually have a circular reference; the issue is that, at the time you define Album, you haven't defined Image yet. You can fix that by using a string instead:

```
class Album(models.model):
  thumb = models.ForeignKey('Image', null=True, blank=True)
```

However, in this case, you might want to use a [OneToOneField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) instead of a foreign key. (Note that you'll still have to use the trick with the string, though).

Comment: Your solution worked but I also had to add `related_name='Image'` to the parameters for the `Album.thumb` definition. What would the advantage of a OneToOneField be over a ForeignKey?

Comment: OneToOneField enforces a unique restriction on the foreign key. Also, you only have to set it on one of the classes, and the other gets the back-link "for free".

Comment: btw, the backlink is for free with the ForeignKey also, but it returns a queryset and not a single item

Answer (score 13):

Use quotes to force a lazy reference:

```
models.ForeignKey('Image', null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, ForeignKey.related_name is your friend (avoids back-reference name clashes).

Comment: @puddingfox you realize you can change the selected correct answer?

Comment: @Kevin: I guess you are familiarized with a currying language like JavaScript, but in Python you have to declare a variable before making a reference (this 'make-it-a-string' trick is a Django convention to handle this fact). Variable currying can be confusing as well - if you have time dive into Python namespaces, it is one of my favorite language traits in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but anyway, i'd like to say that I don't see a reason for attribute album in model Image. In my opinion, it is not really needed.

Comment: I would disagree with you on that - even though it's now quite a while later. He want's his database to allow for there to be only one possible thumbnail for this album. The most natural way to express this is to let images to refer with an FK to an Album and for an album to refer to a single image with an FK. By having an FK on Album you automatically enforce there can only be one. The only alternative ways I can think of to model that would require some comparatively more complex constraints or additional logic in the application code itself to guarantee this.