# How to add django model fields after definition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple django model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    iso_alpha3=models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

I need to add a new field 'default_city' after the class initialization. It has already been added in the DB. How can this be done?

Thank you in advance

UPD: Here's what I want:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    iso_alpha3=models.CharField(max_length=3)
    default_city=VerboseForeignKey(City,display_fields=["name"])

class City(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country=VerboseForeignKey(Country,display_fields=["name"])
```

But I cant do that because I get a NameError: name 'City' is not defined

Comment: What do you mean, "after initialization"? Give an example.

Comment: You mean you added the column manually to the database and now want to access that column from the model?

Comment: You mean 'default_city' is another column which is added to the country table, but it is not present in Model. Now you want to add it into the model class. Am i Right?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman "after initialization" means that I've started defining a new class "City" and only after it has been defined I need to add a new field 'default_city'

Comment: Well, if you've added it to the database already, what's stopping you simply adding the field in the class definition?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman my next 'City' model has a foreign key to Country model. Default_city is a foreign key to City so when I try to add fields before defining City model I get a "NameError: name 'City' is not defined"

Comment: You need to define City model first, if you want to keep the foreign key in country model. Then import the City model into the models.py where you are defining the Country model.

Comment: @sandeep If I define City model first I'll get a "NameError: name 'Country' is not defined" because it has a foreign key to Country model

Comment: Sigh. That's a completely different problem, which you should have mentioned initially, and which has been answered many times here: see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895454/django-app-dependency-cycle/896995#896995).

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I didn't say anything about models being in different apps. Please see the update I've made in my initial post.

Comment: The solution is the same: use a string, not a class, in the FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my initial problem was in circular foreign keys and similar topics have been answered already.

The solution is to use quotes for the model:

```
default_city=VerboseForeignKey('City',display_fields=["name"])
```

Similar topics:

[Django models.py Circular Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682513/django-models-py-circular-foreign-key)

[Django App Dependency Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895454/django-app-dependency-cycle)